# How to hide error message from Jasmine expect function

Tags: javascript, testing, jasmine

Using the Jasmine expect function to check if a large array contains a value like this:

```
expect(a).toContain(b);
```

But the array is quite large so produces ugly results on the webpage, is it possible to only show a list of the values which are missing? so that would be a list of 'b' values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to have [`jasmine2-custom-message`](https://github.com/avrelian/jasmine2-custom-message) **replace** the assertion error message:

```
since("my custom message").expect(a).toContain(b);
```

If you are still on jasmine-1.x, you can use [`jasmine-custom-message`](https://github.com/avrelian/jasmine-custom-message).